# ios conditional tableview cell rendering

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view, uibutton

I am currently working on a swift based HRM project. where it requires to show a tableview with slightly customized cell. cells it self containing two buttons, under some business logic one button would be hidden. for example ,

if the current user is the employee himself , he can see a list, the cell containing his name can see two buttons,but other cell would show simply one button.
i have tried the followings:
1. if the userId == employeeId (employeeId came from a model) then ,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClaimTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ClaimTableViewCell

        if(self.claimdata[indexPath.section].employeeId  == self.empId) {

            cell.CancelButton.isHidden = false


        }
```

also , i have tried

```
if(self.claimdata[indexPath.section].employeeId  != self.empId) {

                cell.CancelButton.frame.size.height = 0


            }
```

works fine for the first frame , the problem begins when i begin to scroll. for some unintended cell it also shows two buttons.

Am I missing something?

Comment: As tableView cell is reusableCell **dequeueReusableCell withIdentifier** you just need to give else condition so when it reuse the cell again it knowns what to do with CancelButton.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to the cell reusability in UITableView.

Use below code in your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method.

```
cell.CancelButton.isHidden = true

if(self.claimdata[indexPath.section].employeeId  == self.empId) {
        cell.CancelButton.isHidden = false
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As tableView cell is reusableCell

> dequeueReusableCell withIdentifier

you just need to give else condition so when it reuse the cell again it knowns what to do with CancelButton.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClaimTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ClaimTableViewCell

        if(self.claimdata[indexPath.section].employeeId  == self.empId) {

            cell.CancelButton.isHidden = false

        }else{

            cell.CancelButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```